# How to avoid touchpoints used by Tangibles in multitouch screen while using TangibleEngine in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a touch user interface where Tangibles with different footprints will be placed on the screen. And I need to find the unassociated touchpoints.

Please refer the pseudo code below. I have tried with the method from the Tangible Engine library. As per the description it should return an array of unassociated touch points, but in my case its also registering associated touch points.

```
public Text Unassociated;

public void OnClick()
{
    TangibleEngine tangibleEngineInstance = TangibleEngine.Instance;
    var y = tangibleEngineInstance.UnassociatedTouchPoints[0].position;
    Unassociated.text = y.ToString();
}
```

It might also be a bug in the library or might be due to some integration issue with UnityEngine. I dont have much expirence with this package and i did not find any other resource for my problem. Hope someone stackoverflow community has a solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately the [Documenatation](https://tangibleengine.com/documentation/guide/UnityBinding.html#setting-up-the-engine) is very sparse and we don't have access to the SDK so I fear it's hard for us to help here. How about directly asking their [Support](https://support.ideum.com/)?

Comment: Yes its difficult to work with non existing documentation. Thanks @derHugo i will try to report this bug. Fortunately i did find an unconventional solution to this by changing screen resolution. Hoplefully the [support](https://support.ideum.com) will solve this issue. I will post solution for this if this bug is not resolved.